# T duality for lower codimension branes or ALF spaces

Tags: string-theory, geometry, duality

These are purely mathematical questions in some sense but I believe this is relevant in string theory as the title says.

I wonder if it is possible to perform [T-duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-duality) of [Taub-NUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taub%E2%80%93NUT_space) space not along the $S^1$-fibration (maybe usually seen cases) but along one of directions in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It looks terrible to me because of the follwoing naive reason:

In the long distance limit (compared to the radius of the compactified circle), the Taub-NUT monopoles become vortices in two dimension and this allows some monodromy.
(Of course, I know the system of 7-branes allowing monodromies usually used in F-theory.)
I heard talks about the objects called exotic branes which appears to be related to the question but I do not know how related not being familiar to those.
In addition, I do not know whether the T-duality works well or not preserving the backgroud supersymmetry.

The another point I would like to care about is $S^1$ compactification breaks the $SO(3)$ isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ where the monopoles live and also does the trisymplectic structures associated to the space rotation. I think this doesn't break the SUSYs but does R-symmetry seemingly (for the dimensionally reduced theory), is it true ?
(This is the same as the T-duality on flat space-time case but I'm confused now.)

Furthemore, can we perform another T-duality in other direction in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?
(I think third times T-dualities operation is impossible because of the compactness (3-torus $T^3$) for the monopoles i.e. maybe anomalous.)

I'm sorry it is rambling.
Summarize the main points of questions,

1). Is it possible to carry out such T-dualities for Taub-NUT spaces ?

2). If so, is the dual space hyper-Kähler (or 16 SUSYs preserved in the compactification in type IIA/B) and what are expressions of triholomorphic forms? Is the quaternionic structure nontrivial?

I'd be pleased to also be given some references in addition to direct answers.